# Find number in line s.startswith python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

For example I have a some text fragment in file:

```
         Item               Value     Threshold  Converged?
 Maximum Force            0.009497     0.000450     NO 
 RMS     Force            0.002723     0.000300     NO 
 Maximum Displacement     0.247463     0.001800     NO 
 RMS     Displacement     0.065734     0.001200     NO 

 SCF Done:  E(RPW91-PW91) =  -2381.36459172     A.U. after    1 cycles
```

And I try to extract two numbers from columns *Value* and *Threshold*, for each lines. For example consider first line

```
 Maximum Force            0.009497     0.000450     NO
```

So, for example I try to get the value `0.009497`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import glob
import os


def CutMAXFValue( Line: str) -> float:
    return float(Line.split()[2]) 

def CutSCFValue( Line: str) -> float:
    return float(Line.split()[4]) 

def GrepSCF( Filename: str , StartStep = 1):
   #print(Filename)
    result = list()
    Step = StartStep
    with open(Filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for s in lines:
        if s.startswith("SCF Done:"):
            result.append( (Step, CutSCFValue(s) ) )
            Step += 1
    return result  


def GrepMAXF( Filename: str , StartStep = 1):
   #print(Filename)
    result = list()
    Step = StartStep
    with open(Filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for s in lines:
        if s.startswith("Maximum Force"):
            result.append( (Step, CutMAXFValue(s) ) )
            Step += 1
    return result  


def DraftListSteps(f: str):
    result = list()
    SubFiles = GetOutFilesBeginsWith( f ) #support function to read from file
    MaxRerun = GetMaxRerun( SubFiles )
    startstep = 1
    for rerun in range(MaxRerun+1):
        RFiles = GetFilesForRerun( SubFiles, rerun )
        DoneFile = next( x for x in RFiles if x.endswith("out") or x.endswith("outERR") )
        MAXF = GrepMAXF(DoneFile, startstep)
        MinStep = min(MAXF, key = lambda x: x[1] )
        startstep = MinStep[0]
        result.append(MAXF)

        # SCF = GrepSCF(DoneFile, startstep)
        # MinStep = min(MAXF, key = lambda x: x[1] )
        # startstep = MinStep[0]
        # result.append(SCF)
    return result
```

And after run script I get the sam error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forker.py", line 123, in <module>
    draft = DraftListSteps( f )
  File "forker.py", line 91, in DraftListSteps
    MinStep = min(MAXF, key = lambda x: x[1] )
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

***How to fix this error and extract required value?*** So, regexp don't work in tis case, thoug maybe I wrong code pattern for regexp...

If I exctract value of `-2381.36459172` from SCF Done fragment this code work perfectly, but if I use code for get `0.009497` it's not work...

Comment: Why not use `csv` or `pandas` to process your text file?

Comment: I suspect there's a tab between `Maximum` and `Force`, not a space. So the `if` condition is not successful.

Comment: This files conatains the complex sctructure, so I don't know work with this files using pandas. And this file not csv is .out (spec text gaussian file, but in my case it consider usual text file)

Comment: @Barmar
This tab is space but is no tabulation \t.. If this tab not is space, how to split this line and extract value?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: If it's space then your `.startswith()` would have worked. So I think it's actually `\t`.

Comment: @alex, `csv` is pretty versatile. If you're sure, for example, that your fields have no embedded spaces, you can create a `csv.Dialect` with `delimiter=' '`  (or `'\t'` if they're tab-deliminated as the other comments suggest) and `skipinitialspace=True`; and split on the space- or tab-deliminated fields. That will fail if you have a field value that includes spaces, but if you're certain that's not the case, it's very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet anything it's a TAB between `Maximum` and `Force`, so change

```
if s.startswith("Maximum Force"):
```

to

```
if s.startswith("Maximum\tForce"):
```

Or you can handle either with a regular expression:

```
if re.match(r'Maximum\s+Force', s):
```

Comment: This construtuion work, but the error not fix so,  if I have sample:
` SCF Done:  E(RPW91-PW91) =  -1236.37513107     A.U. after   17 cycles` this code work and extract value -1236.37513107, but if I neen extract value 0.009497,  error is not disappear...

Comment: `0.009497` is in `line.split()[2]`, not `line.split()[4]`

Comment: `Line.split()[4]` contains `NO`.

Comment: @Bramar

Sorry, I change earlier sample line.split()[2]... Probably, problem in         
`MAXF = GrepMAXF(DoneFile, startstep)
        MinStep = min(MAXF, key = lambda x: x[1] )`

in fact,  I would like to replace one number with another - everywhere there is one line, and in this case, it is not entirely clear why in the case of SCF Done: everything works, but with the same value from the line Maximum Force such an error ...

Comment: I don't know what `SCF Done` is. I don't see that anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Bramar
I edit and add detail information. Sorry, I I assumed that the problem was tabulation in the record, but apparently the situation is different...

Comment: Shouldn't `GrepSCF` use `.startswith('SCF Done:)`?

Comment: Is there a space before `Maximum Force`? It doesn't line up with `SCF Done`, so it looks like it's indented.

Comment: SCF Done not indented, like Maximum Force...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246791/discussion-between-barmar-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

An example of reading this using `csv` (without actually bothering with a `Dialect`):

```
with open(inputfile_name) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    datarows = [row for row in reader if row[0] != "Item"] #filter out headers
    print(datarows)
```

Or, if it's tab-delimited:

```
with open(inputfile_name_t) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t', skipinitialspace=True)
    datarows = [row for row in reader if row[1] != "Item"] #filter out headers
    print(datarows)
```

prints (cleaned up for clarity):

```
[['Maximum', 'Force', '0.009497', '0.000450', 'NO', ''], 
 ['RMS', 'Force', '0.002723', '0.000300', 'NO', ''],
 ['Maximum', 'Displacement', '0.247463', '0.001800', 'NO', ''],
 ['RMS', 'Displacement', '0.065734', '0.001200', 'NO', '']]
```

That's for the space-delimited version; the tab-delimited is slightly different output, but still gets you where you need to go.

You might need to adjust the subscript in the filtering line, depending on whether there's a tab or space at start-of-line.